# Setup Yocto Environment using Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, yocto, repo

I'm working on Setup Yocto Environment using Dockerfile through Jenkins. [image]
I need to execute commands step by step in Dockerfile. I'm able to download repo using curl command successful.
Getting errors in repo init execution
Can anyone help me on this[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is `CROPS` project that has a Docker image for Yocto.

For more details check this [link](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/CropsCLIContainers).

Also, there is the `KAS` project which has support for Docker.

Check think [link](https://embeddeduse.com/2021/09/18/setting-up-yocto-projects-with-kas/) to know how to transform your `repo` manifest into `kas` file and than use Docker.

Comment: Here we need to take client base image only and outside images not allowed like from docker hub. So we created Dockerfile in this top client base image from artifactory and executed all related commands step by step.